Bounds Involving Capture Conversion in java
I have doubts about JLS 18.3.2:

18.3.2 Bounds Involving Capture Conversion
When a bound set contains a bound of the form G<α1, ..., αn> = capture(G<A1, ..., An>), new bounds are implied and new constraint formulas may be implied, as follows.
Let P1, ..., Pn represent the type parameters of G and let B1, ..., Bn represent the >bounds of these type parameters. Let θ represent the substitution [P1:=α1, ..., >Pn:=αn].
Let R be a type that is not an inference variable (but is not necessarily a proper type).
A set of bounds on α1, ..., αn is implied, generated from the declared bounds of
P1, ..., Pn as specified in §18.1.3.
In addition, for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n):
• If Ai is not a wildcard, then the bound αi = Ai is implied.
• If Ai is a wildcard of the form ?  :
– αi = R implies the bound false
– αi <: R implies the constraint formula ‹Bi θ <: R›
– R <: αi implies the bound false
...

This is a passage regarding the type inference process.I can't understand what Rrefers to here.
In particular, the definition of R seems to be in contradiction with the previous one:
18.1.1:

The term "type" is used loosely in this chapter to include type-like
syntax that contains inference variables. The term proper type
excludes such "types" that mention inference variables. Assertions
that involve inference variables are assertions about every proper
type that can be produced by replacing each inference variable with a
proper type.

The type of R is not an inference variable. Then what is it if it is not a proper type?
Could you give some examples such that the bound sets of ai = R, ai <: R, and R <: ai occur?

Read the definition of "proper type" again,

The term "type" is used loosely in this chapter to include type-like syntax that contains inference variables. The term proper type excludes such "types" that mention inference variables.

The keyword here is "mention". Any type that mentions any inference variable is not a proper type.
Inference variables themselves obviously mention inference variables, so they are not proper types. Suppose α is an inference variables, types such as List<α> or α[] are also not proper types. These types are not inference variables themselves (these are a parameterised type and an array type respectively), but they mention inference variables.
It is trivial to create a bound of the form α <: R where α is an inference variable and R is not a proper type and also not an inference variable. The initial bound set of calling a method like
<T, U extends List<T>> void f(...) {}

will contain the bound β <: List<α> where α and β are the inference variables for type parameters T and U respectively.
The other forms of bounds you mentioned can probably be created during the other steps of inference (reduction, incorporation, resolution).
